# Comparing 2 huge (5-6 GB) csv files and count the number of matching and unmatched no. of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

There are 2 huge (5-6 GB) each csv files. Now the objective is to compare both these files. how many rows are matching and how many rows are not matching?

Lets say file1.csv contains 5 similar lines, we need to count it as 1 but not 5.
Similarly, for file2.csv if there are redundant data, we need to count it as 1.

I expect the output to display the number of rows that are matching and the no. of rows that are different.

Comment: Load the two files in a Document DB (MongoDb, CouchDB,...) as two collections, with each line of the files with his own hash key. Compare the hash keys to find the matches.

Comment: Are the files in the same order?

Comment: Will that work @framontb if they are identical but one is just missing the first row?

Comment: It will find identical lines without order. First line in a file will match last line of the other.

Comment: Say there are duplicate lines in file1, is it considered same if these duplicate lines be appear in file2 also the same number of times? Can you add all these cases also in your description.

Comment: @framontb The file exist in linux machine and we dont have MongoDb there. We are using Hive.

Comment: I don't know Hive. Perhaps you could use [tranformation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform) to create a hash by line, erase duplicates, then sort, last compare.

Comment: As a first step, I would recommend removing the headers, sorting the lines and removing the duplicates; that can be easily done with command line tools like `tail` (there's a parameter that makes it output everything except the first line), `sort` (for sorting the lines) and `uniq` (for removing the duplicates, after the sorting) and will make the comparison easier/faster afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a file comparer in python that can optimally compare huge files and get matching lines count and different lines count. Replace the input_file1 and input_file2 with your 2 large files and run it. Let me know the results.

```
input_file1 = r'input_file.txt'
input_file2 = r'input_file.1.txt'

__author__ = 'https://github.com/praveen-kumar-rr'

# Simple Memory Efficient high perfomance file comparer.
# Can be used to efficiently compare large files.

# Alogrithm:
# Hashes the lines and compared first.
# Non matching lines are picked as different count.
# All the matching lines are taken and the exact lines are read from file
# These strings undergo same comparison process based on string itself


def accumulate_index(values):
    '''
    Returns dict like key: [indexes]
    '''
    result = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(values):
        indexes = result.get(v, [])
        result[v] = indexes + [i]
    return result


def get_lines(fp, line_numbers):
    '''
    Reads lines from the file pointer based on the lines_numbers list of indexes
    '''
    return (v for i, v in enumerate(fp) if i in line_numbers)


def get_match_diff(left, right):
    '''
    Compares the left and right iterables and returns the matching and different items
    '''
    left_set = set(left)
    right_set = set(right)
    return left_set ^ right_set, left_set & right_set


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Gets hashes of all lines for both files
    dict1 = accumulate_index(map(hash, open(input_file1)))
    dict2 = accumulate_index(map(hash, open(input_file2)))

    diff_hashes, matching_hashes = get_match_diff(
        dict1.keys(), dict2.keys())

    diff_lines_count = len(diff_hashes)

    matching_lines_count = 0
    for h in matching_hashes:
        with open(input_file1) as fp1, open(input_file2) as fp2:
            left_lines = get_lines(fp1, dict1[h])
            right_lines = get_lines(fp2, dict2[h])
            d, m = get_match_diff(left_lines, right_lines)
            diff_lines_count += len(d)
            matching_lines_count += len(m)

    print('Total number of matching lines is : ', matching_lines_count)
    print('Total number of different lines is : ', diff_lines_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this algorithm work**

1. create hash of every line in both file
2. now create set of that hash
3. difference and intersection of that set.